# Running several scripts with forever

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, forever

I have several scripts in  a directory, each of the scripts called bot and it's number, from 1 to the number of the scripts.

What I would like to do is somehow run all of the scripts by 1 command line through the terminal (Using Ubuntu), I've used `forever` command to run the script without stopping and etc.

Could you make it through the terminal or using a node js script?

Is there any other commands like forever that would do it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use it through the command line with the command `forever`.

You'll need to create a `JSON` file with the files you need.

Example:

```
[
  {
    // App1
    "uid": "app1", // ID of the script.
    "append": true,
    "watch": true,
    "script": "bot1.js", // Name of the script
    "sourceDir": "" // Where the script is located. If it's in the
                    // same location as the json file, leave it ""
  },
  {
    // App2 = > Same as app1, just different script name.
    "uid": "app2",
    "append": true,
    "watch": true,
    "script": "bot2.js",
    "sourceDir": ""
  }
]
```

Then you need just to run the `JSON` file through the `forever` command.
Example:

```
forever start apps.json
```

You can see more information about `forever` [here](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever#multi-app-configuration-files).

Answer (score 1):

My answer is the same as the answer by @Nikita Ivanov but with pm2. I personally like pm2, which also uses a config file just like forever, but it can be a js, json or yaml file.

```
// JS File
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "bot1",
    script: "./bot1.js",
    watch: true, // some optional param just for example
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
    }, // some optional param just for example
    env_production : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production"
    } // some optional param just for example
  },{
    name: "bot2",
    script: "./bot2.js",
    instances: 4, // some optional param just for example
    exec_mode: "cluster" // some optional param just for example
  }]
}
```

Now if you do not know the number of scripts there are, it ok. Since it is JS, you can write a script to get the list of all the files in the directory and create an array similar to the one above and use that config for pm2.

```
module.exports = (function () {
    // logic to get all file names and create the 'apps' array
    return {
        apps: apps
    }
})()
```

Furthermore, you can also use the pm2 npm module and use pm2 as a module in a js script and do this.

See [PM2 DOCS](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/) for more info.